# Populate ListView when page is loaded (Xamarin.Forms) using a Command

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have tried unsuccessfully to populate a ListView bound to an ObservableCollection when a page is loaded. Currently I have it working with a button (bound to a Command) with the following code.

View:

```
<Button Text="Load Items" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"></Button>
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" />
<ScrollView>
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">      
    .....
  </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

View.cs:

```
private ItemsViewModel _itemsViewModel;

public ItemsView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _itemsViewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
    BindingContext = _itemsViewModel;
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items{ get; set; }
public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }

public ItemsViewModel()
{
    Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    _isBusy = false;

    LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadItems(), () => !IsBusy);    
}

public async Task LoadItems()
{
    if (!IsBusy)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Delay(3000); 
        var loadedItems = ItemsService.LoadItemsDirectory(); 

        foreach (var item in loadedItems)
            Items.Add(item);

        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly with the button but I have no idea how to do it automatically. I tried binding the RefreshCommand property of the listview to my command but nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of ways, but the best one would be to kick off a task in your view models constructor that loads the data. I would also not add each item to the observable collection as this would mean a UI update on end add. It would be better to replace the collection completely once all data is loaded.

Something like:

```
public ItemsViewModel()
{
    Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    _isBusy = false;

    Task.Run(async () => await LoadItems());    
}

public async Task LoadItems()
{
    var items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(); // new collection

    if (!IsBusy)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Delay(3000); 
        var loadedItems = ItemsService.LoadItemsDirectory(); 

        foreach (var item in loadedItems)
            items.Add(item);                // items are added to the new collection    

        Items = items;   // swap the collection for the new one
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Items)); // raise a property change in whatever way is right for your VM

        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @JimBobBennet. It worked by kicking off the task on the constructor of the view model. However, the swap of the collections didn't work, it only works when I add the items to the public Items property directly in the loop. Also I was under the impression that it is not necessary to invoke the PropertyChanged on ObservableCollections. In my case it is working without that line

Comment: If you add to the existing collection then the UI will update, but it will be slow as the UI will redraw for every item you add. For 1,000 items you're going to have a bad time.

The property change was because in my example it replaces the value of the `Items` property with a brand new collection, so you need to raise the property change to tell it to reload the new collection - leads to 1 UI update

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your clarification @JimBobBennett

Comment: Thanks @JimBobBennett, it works perfectly for me as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: **RaisePropertyChanged** is kind of confusing, would be great if you can share it's implementation or refer the class in which it resides